# What is the default user for Windows 10 services?

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions, services, users

I'm using Sickchill, which runs as a service. Unless I give everyone full control to the show folders, I get a "permission denied" error for the show folder from the Sickchill service.

The service has the default logon settings, which the dialog describes as "Local System account."

[image: Sickchill properties]

I've tried granting access to several different users including SERVICE, and SYSTEM, but the service only seems to be granted access when I grant everyone full control, which I'm not thrilled about.

Comment: Where commercial programs (QuickBooks for example) use a Service that all users need, the Service log on is Local System Account and authenticated. You may wish to put your question to the program authors.